# How to understand "with which facts" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in "The structure of scientific revolutions" - "Attempts to increase the accuracy and scope with which facts like these are known occupy a significant fraction of the literature of experimental and observational science". How to understand "with which facts" here, especially "with"? Is it a decoration of scope?

Comment: No, the facts are more than decoration. Attempts to increase the accuracy and scope **of facts like these** occupy much of science literature.

Comment: 'With which facts like these are known' qualifies 'accuracy and scope'.

Comment: @jsw29 How it 'qualifies', could you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrase:

Facts like these are known but they need to be known more accurately and have a greater scope because they occupy a significant fraction of the literature of experimental and observational science".

**Attempts to increase the accuracy and scope** – Noun phrase = Subject

**with which *(i.e. referering to the accuracy and scope of)* facts like these are known** – adjectival clause modifying “the accuracy and scope”

**occupy** – finite verb

**a significant fraction of the literature of experimental and observational science"** – Noun phrase = Object

**With which it is verbed** - Compare:
This is the soup and this is the spoon with which it is stirred.

Comment: Thanks. Another question is what is the subject of the adjectival clause, I guess it is which, so how about facts then?